# PS to logoff user from list of servers in case account got locked or password changed

Tags: powershell, logout

we are facing this issue a lot  users account got locked becouse of password got change and they didnt signout from servers
i search on google i found this script
powershel run as administrator

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$NameToZap = 'Ani_Admin'

$USERNAME = 0
$SESSIONNAME = 1
$ID = 2

Get-Content -path C:\Scripts\ServerNamesL.txt |
    ForEach-Object{
        $x = quser /server:$
        for ($i = 1; $i -lt $x.count; $i++){    # skip the header
            $y = $x[$i].split(" ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[$USERNAME..$ID]  # get the 1st 3 columns of data
            if ($y[$USERNAME] -eq $NameToZap){
                logoff $y[$ID] /server:$_           # log off the session id
            }
    }
}
```

i got this error

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.

The creditional i used is a global admin to run the script

Comment: A better approach would be to sign off idle RDP sessions (disconnected sessions) automatically after X hours have passed. You can set this via GPO.

Comment: The `$` in `$x = quser /server:$` should be `$_`: `$x = quser /server:$_`